# GridSplitter not working

Tags: c#, wpf, gridsplitter

Trying to use `GridSplitter` but it's not working. Dragging the splitter to the left is fine, but dragging to the right has no effect. I think the Right grid is the problem. But I'm not sure. Please give me some advice.

Here is my code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="{DynamicResource DefaultMargin}"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="columnDefinition_One" Width="{DynamicResource DefaultMargin}"/>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="columnDefinition_Two" MinWidth="230" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Element1}"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="Layout" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">

    </Grid>
    <GridSplitter x:Name="gridSplitter" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ResizeDirection="Columns" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Background="{StaticResource DarkGray}" />
    <Grid x:Name="grid_MonitoringView" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Style="{DynamicResource DefaultPanel}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Border>
        <view1:ViewExample x:Name="viewExample"/>
    </Border>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Your last line `<Grid>` should be `</Grid>`.

Comment: @walterlv Yeah that was my mistake but still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Your code in my demo project]

I copied your code into my demo project, and it works fine for me. @lomed found that you might have an incorrect `MinWidth` value and I agree with that too. But you say that your 'grid_MonitoringView' has not been affected.

Do you notice that my right border layout correctly? So the real problem is `ViewExample` class. Your `ViewExample` has incorrect layout values such as `MinWidth` or other visuals inside with larger layout width.

Comment: Yeah Thank you for your information. The real problem is the ViewExample class. ViewExample Class doesn't getting bigger or smaller.

Answer (score 0):

the GridSplitter cant reduce width of column than their MinWidth value.

You'll see it works fine if you maximize the window, 
or for demostartion try remove the MinWidth value:

```
<ColumnDefinition />
<ColumnDefinition x:Name="columnDefinition_One" Width="50"/>
<ColumnDefinition x:Name="columnDefinition_Two"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that's not a solution. I can move to left or right but gridspiltter doesn't effect to left grid 'grid_MonitoringView'